# netrw: have the cursor placed on previous cwd name when going up dir

Tags: filesystem, netrw

In a netrw listing, when I press `-` key to go up a directory, I would like the cursor placed on the line corresponding to the dir I have just left (exactly how happens on some file managers, e.g. Nemo).

For example:
I'm in a directory named 'foo', I press `-` and on the listing of parent dir, the cursor is placed on the line corresponding to 'foo/'.

Is there a way to instruct netrw to do so?

Answer (score 2):

After some attempts, I found a tailored solution which works for me (feel free to improve on it).

I save the name of current directory, go up dir, then search the name of saved cwd (with trailing `/`) to place the cursor on previous directory name line.
Also I mapped this key-sequence to the `<Backspace>` key (to be active on a netrw buffer only).

Here is the line I added to my .vimrc file:

`au FileType netrw nmap <buffer> <Backspace> :let @z=expand("%:t")<CR>-/\<<C-R>=@z<CR>/\><CR>`

Comment: Ok, I discovered that  https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar  by Tim Pope does the same thing (and other useful stuff), so I just installed it. I guess that guy knows Vim little better than me :)